# Can everyone join the Tribunal?

Tags: league-of-legends

I heard a friend talking about a LoL Tribunal. Can everyone join it? How long does it take to get back from maintenance? Are there any perks if I belong to the tribunal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can everyone join it?

Any summoner that is level 20 (Formerly 30) who isn't currently banned can participate in reviewing Tribunal cases. A summoner can review up to 20 cases a day. Summoners receive a Justice Rating based on how often their votes coincide with the majority vote on cases. On the contrary, if a player repeatedly votes against the majority, they will lose the access to the Tribunal. This system is used to encourage players to read thoroughly their assigned cases, instead of blindly punishing people.

> How long does it take to get back from maintenance?

Nobody knows

> There are any perks if i belong to the tribunal?

At some point in the future, people may also be given rewards depending on their Justice Rating.

Comment: As far as perks, it's probably worth mentioning that they rewarded IP for each case (or maybe only each case in which your vote was in the majority?).  This is of course subject to change in the revamp, but its an indication that they intend to reward tribunal members.

Comment: As Tim B's answer, the tribunal doesn't really exist right now, and nobody knows what it's gonna be like if/when it's back.

Answer (score 4):

Riot have said that the tribunal was not really scaling up to handle the number of players in LoL properly and so they suspended it.

They have also said that they aim to release a new tribunal system sometime in 2015 but in the meantime have been working on a lot of other measures (such as ranked restrictions) to help.

Until the new system is ready we won't know what it will look like or how it will work.